# What is wrong with this question title?

Tags: support

What exactly is wrong with the question title

> What is the code after "catch" called?

[image: screenshot]

I have then changed it to [What is the part after "catch" called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54102994/476074), which was accepted.

Comment: It’s because of the word “code” and the title having a length of less than 41 characters.